# Two Django apps on apache2 server using wsgi?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, apache2, django-wsgi

I am trying to deploy two Django applications on Apache2 server, running on Ubuntu-16.04. My 000-default.conf file is like given below:

**Updated: (Different port)**
 IP which I am using is  172.16.16.68

when I run a single application pep_web, I can connect this application through on browser

```
172.16.16.68/pep_learn
```

and for MyApp through the browser like this

172.16.16/MyApp

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    <Directory /home/bic/MyApp/MyApp>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess MyApp python-path=/home/bic/MyApp:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup MyApp
    WSGIScriptAlias /MyApp /home/bic/MyApp/MyApp/wsgi.py

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html


</VirtualHost>



<VirtualHost *:8080>


    Alias /static /home/bic/pep_web/protocol/static
    <Directory /home/bic/pep_web/protocol/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>


    <Directory /home/bic/pep_web/pep_learn>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess pep_web python-path=/home/bic/pep_web:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup pep_web
    WSGIScriptAlias /pep_learn /home/bic/pep_web/pep_learn/wsgi.py

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


</VirtualHost>
```

With this setting  "MyApp"  is working but not the other application "pep_web".
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Since both are running in same port `80`. You need to add different `ServerName` in each `VirtualHost`

For more [doc](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    <Directory /home/bic/MyApp/MyApp>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess MyApp python-path=/home/bic/MyApp:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup MyApp
    WSGIScriptAlias /MyApp /home/bic/MyApp/MyApp/wsgi.py

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName myapp.com

</VirtualHost>



<VirtualHost *:80>


    Alias /static /home/bic/pep_web/protocol/static
    <Directory /home/bic/pep_web/protocol/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>


    <Directory /home/bic/pep_web/pep_learn>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess pep_web python-path=/home/bic/pep_web:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup pep_web
    WSGIScriptAlias /pep_learn /home/bic/pep_web/pep_learn/wsgi.py

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName mypepapp.com


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


</VirtualHost>
```

Then in `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost
#your local domains
127.0.0.1       myapp.com
127.0.0.1       mypepapp.com
```

Comment: @itzMEonTVTV Thanks for your helpful suggestion, As I am very new at Server and apache can you explain how can I give different server name as I am using only one IP to host both the site without any domain name.

Comment: If you are not using domain, run in different port.If you are working in localhost and accessing in same host, i think you can give local domains in /etc/hosts/

Comment: I tired with different port 80 and 8080 but its given same error.

Comment: can you plz modified the above '.conf' script with an example as u have provided "/etc/hosts". it will help me to understand the concept correctly.  I have seen many posts regarding that And tried everything but nothing has worked.

Comment: Please update your .conf that you tried for different port

Comment: Check my updated answer. I hav a question- If you remove the first block, is the second one working ?

Comment: "If you remove the first block, is the second one working ?" Yess It works in both the cases if I remove either part of the script upper or lower virtual host. But I keep only one virtual host and change the port from 80 to anything alse it stops working.

Comment: You need to add `Listen 8080` on top of your .conf, i mean outside virtualhost, Then you need to access as `172.16.16.68:8080/`

Comment: I have made all the changes as per your answer but it's not working. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162878/discussion-between-itzmeontv-and-jax).